# JQuery Mobile POST data empty in $_POST

Tags: php, post, jquery-mobile, is-empty

I'm running into a problem with JQuery Mobile (new to me) and the AJAX-call. I'm using the following code:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://**correct url**/post/todoitem",
            beforeSend: addHeaders,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: { "todoitem":"test" }, // this is just as a test
            success: function(result) {
                alert("Success: " + JSON.stringify(result));
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("Error: " + JSON.stringify(arguments));
            }
        });
```

While executing this, it calls a PHP script where I need the data from the todoitem, so in this case the string "text" (in the end, multiple variables are to be send, but for now I'm just using one parameter for simplicity).

My PHP code looks like this (also just for testing purposes):

```
echo json_encode($_POST));
```

The result is: nothing, null. The $_POST seems to be empty. I've searched and tried many things, but most answers (even here on stackoverflow) are about forms and people say I need to serialize the contents of the form. However, I'm not using a form at all.

I also tried

```
data: JSON.stringify({ "todoitem" : "test" })
```

as some suggested but this did not work either.
I do know that the data is being transfered because of this little PHP hack I tried:

```
echo file_get_contents('php://input');
```

That exactly shows the data: todoitem = test. So where does this all go wrong? I'm working on this for days now! Thnx in advance

Comment: what device you're testing this on? and what jQuery and jQuery Mobile versions?

Comment: why don't you use $.post and call addHeaders before executing it?
I think maybe it's doing a get instead

Comment: It's not doing a GET, PHP just doesn't decode application/json :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with this part of your code:

```
contentType: "application/json",`
```

Removing that line should make the sent `Content-Type` header default to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and PHP will decode the request into `$_POST`.

Comment: This seems to work. Very strange, as I actually added that line as I saw that on another website during my search. So at first, I didn't even had that line there (and I once had 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' there as well). Probably did something else wrong than I guess. Anyone thanks for the help!